# Limiting NGINX reverse proxying to https only

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have an NGINX reverse proxy configured to forward to different ports on the same machine based on the request URL. I have `service1` on port 8070 and `service2` on port 8071. 
This is my nginx config

```
upstream service1 {
   server 127.0.0.1:8070;
}

upstream service2 {
   server 127.0.0.1:8071;
}

server {
   server_name a.example.com;

   location /foo/ {
     proxy_pass  http://service1;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

   location /bar/ {
     proxy_pass  http://service2;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

   listen 80; # managed by Certbot

   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/a.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I need to have port 80 enabled for certbot (lets encrypt) to be able to deploy certificates. I'm using the `python3-certbot-nginx` plugin

The problem right now with this config is that clients can do http (unencrypted) requests to my services via the proxy.

Is there any way I can disable redirecting http requests and make the `location` rule only match https requests so that http requests are not redirected but http is still available for the certbot challenges? If not, is there any other way to have nginx not allow http requests/force https that won't break certbot?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate HTTPS-only `server`, and put the proxying statements in that server.

Comment: how can i do that? all the lines in my config with the comment "managed by Certbot" were added by the certbot nginx plugin. In other words, even if i put `listen 80` on a different server, the nginx plugin will add it to the virtualhost where SSL is configured